# re-using functions across projects in Unity and C#

Tags: c#

I'm quite new to C# and Unity so have mercy on me. I'm using visual studio.

I have what seems like a pretty common problem. Which is - i want to use functions i write across several projects in unity. I don't want to have to go search for the code in some folder, copy paste it into the new project, or fiddle with symbolic links or use .dll's. These are all not great solutions to the problem. Can't i just somehow create a class I can access across all my projects? Custom namespace perhaps that is not project specific? that i can simply just call at the beginning of wherever i want to use my homemade scripts.

Comment: DLLs are the solution here. You put the common classes in a DLL, and reference it in all your projects.

Comment: make a project and only write common code in there , and export unity package for other project , when you import it's new version , unity be update well .

Comment: DLL is a greate solution also , And write ".bat" to help you move the dll automatically

Comment: Symbolic links would also really be a great answer here.... Update in one place! Also means breaking other projects though...

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to build a custom DLL and the headache that comes with maintaining its versioning alongside Unity releases, consider building an [AssetPackage](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetPackages.html). You can right-click in one of your projects and export a bunch of scripts that you want to be re-used in other places together as a package. When you start a new project, just load that package into it by dragging and dropping it.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2-3 things to consider in this situation:

- Ease of deployment
- Whether or not you will update that code
- Ease of update, if you will update it

If you just want to bring it in once, then [Erik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57583309/3838167) should be simple enough.
If you want to keep things as an updated library though, you will need another method.

Symbolic links as you mentioned would be the best, or DLLs. However, with this, you'd run the risk of breaking your other projects if you ever modify the common lib from inside your project.

Another option would be to have a separate VCS (git, svn, etc) inside your project for your common code. This way you can update if/when you want, you can roll-back if something breaks, and you can even fork your "common" code to make a project specific change.

---

Since OP mentioned it, in this case, OP could specifically use [Git Submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) or simply add a second Git project and add that sub-Git to the parent's `.gitignore` file

Comment: I really want to avoid the unity package import/export route, it's annoying. Sym links don't work for me. Git submodules, I've read a lot of horror stories about them in use for unity. It seems like the cleanest route is using the DLL option. The one thing I'm not very clear on is if I want to add functions and classes to the DLL once it's created. Because as time goes on I'll make more tools with different classes and functions that I'll want to add to the DLL. Is it possible to add functionality to an already existing DLL i created? if so, how?

Comment: @shakeNbake You would simply recompile the DLL. But then you have to distribute it again. I don't recall an option to set a common DLL folder in projects either, so you might end up with the symbolic link problem all over again

Comment: @shakeNbake As for git problems with Unity, I haven't heard anything. The feature is *designed* for situations like this, so I can't really imagine anything better!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using git for your projects, you could add the shared code into a separate repository and add them to your projects as a git submodule.